# Is there a way to find the time taken to load the data

Tags: r

I have a huge data that is loaded into R. Indeed it is taking some time to load data. But I need to know how many minuted it took to load the data. Is there a way to find this out. In general, can we find out the time taken to perform certain operation

Comment: You can check `?system.time` or create a `begin/end` object and get the difference;  `begin <- Sys.time(); < yourcode>; end <- Sys.time(); end-begin`.  For loading the data, if you use `fread`, it would give some info